# Wordpress Posts Overlapping

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I just posted this on the Wordpress development stack exchange and they said it would be more suitable here

This is probably a really simple CSS issue but here goes anyway:
I'm developing a Wordpress theme which has a left sidebar and posts on the right, however the posts overlap and I can't get it to just flow down the page.

Because the HTML is part of a loop, the divs are copied multiple times.

[image]

I have a HTML reset further up in the code if that helps anyone.

The code for the posts looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="propbox">
<p class="propertytext"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
<div class="propertybox"></div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.propertybox {

  position: absolute;
  top: 103px;
  left: 43%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 356px;
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.propertytext {

  position: absolute;
  top: 112px;
  left: 56.75%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20.4%;
  min-height: 47px;
  line-height: 1.38;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 31px;

}
```

I can't get this to work!!
Any help is appreciated
Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Can you give us a link to a website? Or a picture of what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
position:absolute;
```

from

```
.propertytext {
}
```

and

```
.propertybox{
}
```

you can give another position.

try it ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `padding-top` to the propertybox class. I made a jsfiddle with your updated code:     http://jsfiddle.net/9ZUyv/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="propbox">
<p class="propertytext"><?php the_title(); ?>dddd</p>
<div class="propertybox">sddssdsdfddasd fasdfasdfadssddss dsdfddasdf asdfasdfadssddssdsdfdd  asdfasdfasdfadssddssdsdfddas dfasdfa sdfadssddssdsdfddasdfasdfasdfads</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.propertybox {
position: absolute;
top: 103px;
left: 43%;
width: 50%;
height: 356px;
background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
margin-top: 15px;
padding-top: 80px
  }

.propertytext {
position: absolute;
top: 112px;
left: 56.75%;
z-index: 1;
width: 20.4%;
min-height: 47px;
line-height: 1.38;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-family: 'Raleway';
font-weight: 200;
font-size: 31px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Howlin, didn't work. Because this is wordpress the HTML is part of a loop so there are multiple copies of the divs - and it still overlaps even with the padding-top :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to accomplish, but try this

```
.propertybox {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.propertytext {

  z-index: 1;
  width: 20.4%;
  min-height: 47px;
  line-height: 1.38;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 31px;

}

.propbox{
  position:absolute;
  top: 103px;
  left: 43%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 356px;
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```